# Does a competitive advantage lead to abnormal profit?

Tags: industrial-organisation, competition, theory-of-the-firm

Given that organisational capital is specific and difficult to replicate it is considered a competitive advantage (see e.g. [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228900943_Organizational_capital_as_competitive_advantage_of_the_firm))

According to [Wang](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285056180_Theories_for_competitive_advantage) (2014)

> competitive advantage is obtained when an organisation develops or acquires a set of
> attributes (or executes actions) that allow it to outperform its
> competitors.

Does a competitive advantage allow a firm to achieve [abnormal profit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abnormal_profit)?
Or which other advantage would it confer?

Comment: wouldn't that be normal profit?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "abnormal" here?

Comment: “Abnormal” in the sense of a profit that cannot be maintained in a competitive market. Organisational capital is difficult to replicate. This suggests that the competitive advantage can be maintained in a competitive market.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. For example, consider a perfect competition scenario, with equilibrium price $p$.

Now say (only) one firm acquires some organizational capital that allows them to have lower their marginal cost from $c(=p)$ to $\tilde c < c$.

This firm can charge price $p^-$ and aquire the whole market now, earning abnormal profits $\pi = (p^- - \tilde c)q$.

Comment: It CAN lead to abnormal profits. Or not. Like, alternatively, this firm can have (near) zero profit and survive in shrinking market, where other firms are either leaving or declaring bankruptcy due to getting negative profits due to shrinking demand.